# Google Docs: Get Sheet Without Name or ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing some scripts for a client with the end goal of complete autonomy -- when complete, the spreadsheet will always work forever. Ideally, anyways.

Because I need information from other sheets, I have to access them in a way other than `.getActiveSheet()`. Because the client might re-name or re-order the sheets, I have to access the sheet in a way that works even after those changes. This rules out `getSheetByName()` and `getSheets()[SHEET_NUMBER]` (again, the client might re-name or re-order the sheets). However, it *should* be possible because of the "gid." Each sheet has a different gid and they do not change when you re-order or re-name the sheets (scroll to the end of the URL for each sheet to see what I mean).

All of the URL accesses only open the FIRST sheet. For instance,
`SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getDataRange().getValues()`
returns the values of the first sheet, *even if* I include the "gid" part at the end. Same with `openById` and `openFile`.

So my question is, how do I access a sheet in a way that will work even after renaming the sheet or reordering the sheets within the spreadsheet?

Comment: Using the gid is a neat idea, but I'm afraid, there is no provision to do so at the moment. I think you should open a request in the Issue tracker for this ( code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list ) and list the issue number here.

Comment: I really do not quite understand what you need, the use case does not seem very clear. Need a script on Apps Script? Are you using the fomula ImportRange(spreadsheet_key, [sheet!]range)?

The option to save the ID sheet [getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getSheetId()) in [Class ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties), for example, then consult and have access to the sheet you need. Would it be useful?

Answer (score 2):

There's no `getSheetById` method, but you can build your own using [getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId%28%29). Here:

```js
function sheetsIdMap() {
  var sheetsById = {};
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(function(s){ sheetsById[s.getSheetId()] = s; });

  //just checking that it worked
  for( var id in sheetsById )
    Logger.log(id+' - '+sheetsById[id].getName());

  //usage example
  var sId2 = sheetsById[2];
  Logger.log('\n'+sId2.getName());
}
```

**-- edit**

Let's try a more straightforward function (although I don't like to do such a loop and don't store the data on a map for subsequent use o(1)).

```js
function getSheetById(ssID, sheetID) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets();
  for( var i in sheets )
    if( sheets[i].getSheetId() == sheetID )
      return sheets[i];
  return null; //sheet id not found in spreadsheet, probably deleted?
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this shows only how to get the sheet ID. I know how to do that. The question was, how do I access a sheet using that ID? `SpreadsheetApp.openById(NUMBER)` returns a "Bad Value" error, and pasting the whole url with `gid=NUMBER` at the end returns the first sheet in the spreadsheet no matter the NUMBER.

Comment: Well, maybe I misunderstood you question. Anyway, there's two concepts here, the *spreadsheet* which you can open using its ID or URL normally, that can have several sheets inside it. These sheets also have IDs, but there's no method to get them using their ID. the code I provided reads all sheets on a spreadsheet and create a map indexing them using these IDs. Therefore enabling one to get a sheet by its ID easily.

Comment: You are confusing the apis. SpreadsheetApp.openById opens a SPREADSHEET not a sheet. In that spreadsheet object you can the open by sheet id.

Comment: Zig is correct. I want to open a sheet within a spreadsheet without knowing about either in the first place. Seems this can't be done.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You can "get" a sheet by its name, position or id. You just have to work a little harder for the latter. But if you don't know anything about the sheet you want to open, how are you going to match it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a sheet id. Its sheet.getSheetId. this id can be used from apps script and can also be transformed into a "real" gid for making a sheet url.  Do (sheetId ^ 31578).toString(36) to get the gid.
I had to reverse-eng it to get it and I cant guarantee it will work forever.

Comment: Using `((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId())^ 31578).toString(36)` returns "od8". Does that sound right? If so, plugging it into `SpreadsheetApp.openById(HERE)` yields a "Bad Value" error. What am I missing?